Is there a Whitehead theorem for spectra?
Recall the Whitehead Theorem from classical homotopy theory, that two 0-connected spaces are equivalent iff their $\pi_n$'s agree for all $n \geq 1$ that a map between 0-connected spaces inducing isomorphisms on all homotopy groups is an equivalence. The theorem is highly nonconstructive, so let's indeed restrict our attention to the classical homotopy categories of spaces and spectra, $\mathcal{S}, Sp := \text{Stab}(\mathcal{S})$ resp. I am wondering if there is a Whitehead theorem for spectra, in the sense that if $\pi_n(A)\cong \pi_n(B) $ for all $n : \mathbb{Z}$ and spectra $A,B$, then $A \simeq B$ a map of spectra inducing isomorphisms on all homotopy groups is an equivalence of spectra. In the following as well, I liberally equivocate between connective spectra and their corresponding infinite loop spaces.

The classical Whitehead theorem on its own doesn't seem to suffice for such a result even for connective spectra, say, the infinite loop spaces $K\mathbb{Z}, K\mathbb({Z \times Z})$ have isomorphic $\pi_0$ sets and all higher homotopy groups vanish for each, but $\mathbb{Z}, \mathbb{Z\times Z}$ are certainly non-isomorphic groups. One idea to remedy this is to ask for isomorphic $\pi_0$'s *as groups*, and this seems to solve the case of infinite loop spaces: as the action of the abelian group $\pi_0(A)$ is an equivalence for all $a : A$, we ought to be able to "transport" the equivalence magically given by Whitehead for the connected components of the identity of $A,B$ with $\pi_0$ so each 0-connected component is $\pi_0$-equivariantly equivalent. More ambitiously, this should work for $k$-connected spectra $A,B$ for any $k < 0$, by looking at the connective components of $\Sigma^k A, \Sigma^k B$.
(Alternatively, perhaps, to avoid that leap of faith with $\pi_0$, do everything with 0-connected spectra instead, by looking at the connected components of $\Sigma A, \Sigma B$ when they're infinite loop spaces and suspending $k+1$ times in the negatively-connected case; this lets us directly use Whitehead unproblematically as $\pi_0$ then vanishes.)

What would remain, then, is the general case of spectra that may even fail to be connected in all degrees, e.g. the topological $K$-theory spectra, and I'm not familiar with any parlor tricks to upgrade classical Whitehead to the stable case here. Does it in fact hold? and is the proof sketch for $k$-connected spectra outlined above sound, in particular is it in fact an equivalence of infinite loop space structures rather than merely an equivalence of homotopy types?

Whitehead doesn't say that two spaces with equivalent $\pi_n$ for all $n$ are homotopy equivalent, it says that a map between CW-complexes inducing an isomorphism on all homotopy groups is a homotopy equivalence. Even if all homotopy groups are isomorphic such a map need not exist.

See https://mathoverflow.net/q/3540/117693

It's true that a morphism $f\colon X\to Y$ in the $\infty$-category of spectra is an equivalence iff it induces isomorphisms (of abelian groups) on all homotopy groups. You can derive it from the Whitehead theorem for spaces since $f$ is an equivalence iff all components $f_i\colon X_i\to Y_i$ are equivalences of spaces. This proof must be written up somewhere, but I don't immediately know where.

@LukasHeger ah, yes, my bad. I'll edit the question.

@DaniëlApol I'll give that approach a try! Could just be folklore too...

This is Corollary 3.5 in part III of Adams' blue book (p. 168 in the newly typeset version). You have to restrict to CW spectra, though, as you do with topological spaces.

Amazing! Thank you for the reference.
